# Jquery mobile with django urls

Tags: jquery, django, mobile

When working with django and jquery mobile, I m stuck with multi page view. Then having had some experiments.
a typical django url is like that.

```
/sale/detail/02_O1_00000036
```

if I try to link several pages with ids.

```
/sale/detail/02_O1_00000036#popupItem10
/sale/detail/02_O1_00000036#popupItem20 ...
```

And apropriate linking made a `href="#popupItem10"`

it doesnt work.

But if I copy the populated html and put it in a html file.
url becomes

```
/sale/detail/02_O1_00000036.html
```

and

```
/sale/detail/02_O1_00000036.html#popupItem10 ...
```

it works, it may be the html tag aftere url. its the only difference.

Can you tell me the difference and how to overcome this?

Comment: can you post the relevant url configuration in Django (urls.py)?

Comment: I would post the complete code but, it works with a private webservice, and no way to get it working here. but url.py is as follows.
project1/urls.py    url(r'^sale/', include('weberp.sale.urls')),

project1/sale/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^home/$', home),
    (r'list/order/today', listordertoday),
    (r'detail/(?P<company>[-\w]+)_(?P<doctype>[-\w]+)_(?P<docnum>[-\w]+)', saledetail),
    #(r'sale/list', listpurreq),
)

Comment: in the template I create links using this.
<a href="#popupItem{{ item|key:'ITEMNUM' }}" data-transition="pop">;

and I crete another page with this
<div data-role="page" id="popupItem{{ item|key:'ITEMNUM' }}">